# Merge dataframe with another dataframe while groupby on the fly

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (df1) with a column that is corresponds to being melted from another dataframe (df0). So in df1 I have a "feature" column which can be "Material", "Customer" etc. from df0 and then a "value" column in df1, which would be the same value in df0 in the corresponding "feature" column. For instance in df1 I have df1.feature = 'Material' and df1.value = 'Car'. In df0 I would have a column df1.Material which would contain a valua called 'Car'.

I need to get the total "Revenue" from df0, for each value in df1. My problem is that I can't use a merge as the df1.feature is not present as one column in df0, but would be either df0.Material, df0.Customer etc. I can pivot df1 so the df1.feature would be multiple columns and then make some groupby's for df0 and merge them to df1, but that seems very inefficient.

Can I somehow make a function or similar, where df1 gets the grouped value of df0 depending of what column name and value is in df1.feature and df1.value?

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'feature': ['Material', 'Material', 'Customer'],
                    'value': ['Car', 'Bike', 'Trump'],
                    'Coefficient1': [1, 2, 3],
                    'Coefficient2': [5,6,7]})



   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Material': ['Car', 'Car','Watch'],
                    'Customer': ['Clinton', 'Obama', 'Trump'],
                    'Revenue': [100, 200, 300],
                    'Margin': [10, 20, 3]})
```

df0

```
   feature    value  Coefficient1      Coefficient2
0   Material    Car     1                 5
1   Material    Bike    2                 6
2   Customer    Trump   3                 7
```

df1

```
       Material     Customer    Revenue    Margin
0   Car             Clinton      100       10
1   Car             Obama        200       20
2   Watch           Trump        300        3
```

What I would like is then in df0 to have:

```
feature       value coefficient1 coefficient2 Revenue    Margin
Material      Car   1             5            300       15
Material      Bike  2             6            NaN       NaN
Customer      Trump 3             7            300       3
```

Comment: Add some example data and expected output based on that example data. It's easier to understand your problem if we can visually see what you want to do, then to read through lot of text.

Comment: I have updated with the dataframes and output - hope that helps :-)

Comment: How did you get the value `300` at `Revenue` and `15` at `Margin` in your expected output in the first row? Is that the `sum` and `average`? What is the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way including [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) , [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
m=(df1.melt(['Revenue','Margin'],var_name='feature')
   .groupby(['feature','value'],as_index=False).agg({'Revenue':'sum','Margin':'mean'}))
final=df0.merge(m,on=['feature','value'],how='left')
```

---

```
    feature  value  Coefficient1  Coefficient2  Revenue  Margin
0  Material    Car             1             5    300.0    15.0
1  Material   Bike             2             6      NaN     NaN
2  Customer  Trump             3             7    300.0     3.0
```

Where the result of `print(m)` is:

```
    feature    value  Revenue  Margin
0  Customer  Clinton      100      10
1  Customer    Obama      200      20
2  Customer    Trump      300       3
3  Material      Car      300      15
4  Material    Watch      300       3
```